# Navbar queda encima del inicio de la sección al hacer scroll

Tags: scroll, navbar

Como puedo dar ese espacio del navbar al activar el scroll, para que este no quede encima del inicio de la sección a la cual el botón me dirige?

Lo que intento es que el alto del navbar sea considerado por el scroll y que la sección a la cuál me drige inicie después del navbar.

En el snipet sólo está el código de JS que ejecuta el scroll, los estilos css del navbar y el navbar hecho con bootstrap, favor su ayuda ya que no encuentro solución en ninguna parte.

Este es el link de prueba del sitio, al hacer click en los botones del menú se puede visualizar lo que menciono

https://skironghost.github.io/montajes_jm/#galeria

Gracias.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    var destino = $(this.hash);
    if (destino.length == 0) {
      destino = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');
    }
    if (destino.length == 0) {
      destino = $('html');
    }
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: destino.offset().top }, 1500);
    return false;
    });
```

```css
.navbar{
  background-color: #282424 !important;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
     background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(255, 192, 5, 1)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
.navbar .collapse a{
  color: #E9DADA !important;
  padding: 12px;
}
.navbar .collapse a:hover{
  background-color: #FFCD38;
  color: #282424 !important;
} 
.navbar .collapse a:active{
  background-color: #FFC005;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse p-0" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#servicios">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#clientes">Clientes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#galeria">Galería</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: El navabar está encima del inicio de la sección]

Comment: Por favor considera colocar un [mcve] donde logremos reproducir el problema y por ende proponer una solución

Comment: Creo que mi mejor opción es subir la página a un repositorio de github para que se pueda visualizar lo que menciono al hacer click en los menu

Comment: No requerimos toda la página, solo el código mínimo necesario para reproducir tu ejemplo, por favor edita y mejora la pregunta

Comment: intenté hacerlo, pero me fuerza a meter casi todo el código de la página, porque debo anclar los links de bootstrap que el repoductor no los lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta línea de tu JS:

```javascript
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: destino.offset().top }, 1500);
```

Resta la altura de tu navbar, así:

```javascript
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: destino.offset().top - $("nav").height() }, 1500);
```

Ello debería alinear el borde inferior de tu navbar con el borde superior de tu "destino".

Comment: Sos un crá.. me resultó, soy terrible novato en esto. Agradezco caleta tu ayuda. Un abrazo y que tengas un feliz año.

Comment: Genial. Feliz año